# Are reverse method references possible in Java 8?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I know about [lambda method references](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html).

However, I am wondering whether the reverse might be possible, because I have a method that just proxies its arguments to a lambda:

```
Function<Arg, Result> lambda = (a) -> new Result(a);

public Result myMethod(Arg arg) {
    return lambda.apply(a);
}
```

Haven't found anything on Google, so I guess it's not possible. Which makes sense, because after all, as I understand it, a lambda is just shorthand for a whole interface. A method and an interface are different. But you can make a lambda from a method, so maybe you can make a method from a lambda?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. Are you looking for syntax that would simplify invoking `lambda.apply(a);`?

Comment: Hi @SotiriosDelimanolis. I'm messing around with the idea of defining lambdas and then making them accessible via class methods. I guess that's not necessary cause I could just define the classes and then use method reference to make the lambdas?

Comment: In your example, you've initialized a variable `lambda` (whether through a lambda expression or otherwise) and used it in the method `myMethod`. Is that what you are referring to with the first sentence of your comment?

Comment: Yes, that is what I am referring to. Unlike other types though, lambda variables seem isomorphic to methods, at least superficially. Anyway, this question is curiosity based. Not practical.

Answer (score 3):

You can't make a method from a lambda because, as you say, a lambda is not a method and more importantly you cannot dynamically change a class by adding methods to it at runtime. That's a basic design invariant of Java classes. It is possible to dynamically respond to a predefined method of an interface with your own implementation, although it's fairly clunky. Take a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html

Answer (score 3):

The variable `lambda` has the type `Function` which doesn’t say anything about how the instance has been created. It might be a lambda expression, but it doesn’t have to. That said, if you want to delegate `myMethod` to a method declared in `Function`, there is no reason to automatically choose the `abstract` method of that `interface`, so, similar to method references, you would have to specify the target method like `lambda::apply` to make clear you want that method and not one of the [other methods of the `interface Function`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/function/Function.html).

But unlike method references, which use a target type, you can’t derive a method declaration from the surrounding context, so you can’t spare the method declaration. So such a hypothetical feature would still require the method declaration, the reference to the `lambda` field and the target method name (`apply`), so there is not much left that you can save that would justify a new language feature.

And there is no need for such a functionality anyway. If you have code to be expressed as both, a function and a method, express it as method:

Instead of

```
Function<Arg, Result> lambda = (a) -> new Result(a);

public Result myMethod(Arg arg) {
    return lambda.apply(a);
}
```

write

```
Function<Arg, Result> lambda = this::myMethod;

public Result myMethod(Arg arg) {
    return new Result(arg);
}
```

---

But even a code replication might be acceptable, as in

```
Function<Arg, Result> lambda = (a) -> new Result(a);

public Result myMethod(Arg arg) {
    return new Result(arg);
}
```

considering that lambda expressions should host rather small, often trivial, code only.